# How to uninstall php server monitor?

Tags: command-line, software-uninstall

I've researched quite a bit and haven't found the answer, I've searched every package in my computer and none of them were from phpservermon so I couldn't remove it through terminal. The version I have is 3.3.2.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: through here <localhost>/phpservermon/install.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, Phpservermonitor is a web application. Which means it does not install in your system. It is installed in your web server root directory. If you want to completely remove it. Just delete the **phpservermon** folder from your www root directory.

Comment: I've tried this, but when I return to the install page it says it is already installed.

PS: I want to uninstall, because I am unaware of the current password and was asked to re-install it.

Comment: Make sure you remove or empty the connected Database also. Like WordPress, Other web applications are also saved there settings to DB.

Comment: I thought it worked, but it only began to ask for the db information, i tried deleting the db and still it only asked for the db information.

Comment: Actually, it saves all the server settings in config.php and mysql Database. Just delete config.php and empty the DB for resetting the entire application.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck all morning doing this, finally finished thanks to you.